# NginX uses wrong config file

Tags: nginx, configuration, redirect

I have a webserver with NginX and each website in different config file. I've noticed, if I have a site configuration that does not exist anymore (no DNS name or wrong setting whatever) NginX simply redirects me to one of my other sites. Always to the same, so not randomly. How does this work? How NginX decides where to redirect me if the configuration he is supposed to serve is not correct?

Easy example: if I enter the IP address of the server into a browser, I get that specific page loaded in. OFC I haven't set any of the configs to serve the IP address. Do you know how can I change NginX to serve something else or maybe drop an error? Oh yeah, about that

If I go to my IP address, none of the log files are logging anything. While clearly, one site loads in.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's because Nginx defaults to the first website. You can choose the one you want to be default with the [default_server](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/server_names.html) directive.

I don't want Nginx to respond to any domain name, so I do this to send [no response](https://httpstatuses.com/444).

```
# This just prevents Nginx picking a random default server if it doesn't know which
# server block to send a request to
server {
    listen      80 default_server;
    server_name _;
    return      444; # This means "go away", effectively
}
```

Comment: So I should put this server block into my main nginx.conf file?

Comment: I put it into its own site config. It makes no difference where it goes really, Nginx has a line in the nginx.conf that includes sites-enabled/*.conf or similar, so everything in that directory is effectively in the Nginx.conf anyway.

Comment: I'll put it to nginx.conf then since I have about 30-40 other .conf file in sites-enabled :) Cheer Mate!

Comment: If you have 40 config files what's one more?! Please accept the answer if it's worked for you.

Answer (score 1):

If there is no `server` block with a matching `server_name`, the request will be either sent to the `server` with the `default_server` statement in it's `Listen` directive or the first `server` block defined (usually the first in the alphabet when reading multiple config files from a directory).

See http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/request_processing.html and http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/server_names.htm